# XMPP USER PRESENCE SHOW AVAILABLE ALWAYS

Tags: chat, ejabberd, xmppframework

I developed a chat application using ejabbered and  xmppframework,I  want to get the Presence of Other User, while requesting from server its shows online always where as the other resource out of wifi zone.

Exact problem is that ejabbered unable to get ,when any user out of reach from wifi or mobile data, it disconnect from the sever logically but it always shows that user as connected and online, untill we restart ejabbered Server.

Please show me a way to solve that problem.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I am also facing same issue, ejabberd is always giving online presence(For a user who comes online and then disable their wi-fi connection or data provider ),unless and until we go for restart the server.Please help to solve the issue

Comment: Check several socket timeout config of Server OS. I think it's not a problem of ejabberd.

Comment: @KeewonSeo Thanks for your response..we need to check this..let you know soon